# Как заблокировать пользователю доступ к свойствам консоли?

Tags: c++, winapi, консоль, окно

Пишу консольное приложение на C++.

Программно убрал возможность выделения области курсором мыши, но обнаружил, что, перейдя в свойства консоли (правой кнопкой по системному меню окна -> Свойства), можно снова включить выделение. Мне нужно, чтобы никто не мог этого сделать.
Может быть, можно вообще как-то спрятать системное меню или хотя бы как-то заблокировать раздел меню "Свойства"?

Кроме выделения, в свойствах есть и другие опции, которые можно изменить. Хотелось бы этого избежать.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46592932/1991579

Comment: Это явно какая-то проблема XY. Зачем вам это понадобилось? Что будете делать со связкой скриншот + OCR?

Comment: Даже если без скриншотов, всегда можно запустить программу с перенаправлением вывода в файл.

Comment: Выделение - это не все, что мне нужно предотвратить. В свойствах много других опций, которые можно поменять, например, цвет фона, шрифт и прочее.

Comment: Создайте свою консоль, тут других вариантов нет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так как "Свойства" - последний элемент в системном меню, можно убрать его с помощью вот такого кода:

```
HWND hWnd = GetConsoleWindow();
HMENU hMenu = GetSystemMenu(hWnd, false);
int c = GetMenuItemCount(hMenu); 
DeleteMenu(hMenu, c-1, MF_BYPOSITION);
```